# Using OWIN in an ASP.NET MVC application, why do I obtain a DbContext disposed (InvalidOperationException) randomly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, dbcontext

I know this question is too general for SO, and I would’t be surprised if it’ll be closed. Anyway, I try to post here my problem, being sorry if it doesn’t belong here.

I’m working on an ASP.NET MVC application that uses OWIN. Basically, I have:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationActionManager>(ApplicationActionManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationApplicationManager>(ApplicationApplicationManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationMenuManager>(ApplicationMenuManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ReminderManager>(ReminderManager.Create);
        ...
```

The problem is that I get a random **DbContext disposed** (`InvalidOperationException`) issue when I run a query. No `Dispose` method is manually called. I’m not able to get to the source of the problem. I worked to replace every manual instantiation of `ApplicationDbContext` (there were multiple before I started working on the issue), to only use `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>()` instead, with no success.

Unfortunately, I’m not able to give other details, because this is the situation: an error that seems to randomly appear.

Some stack traces:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ReleaseConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__156`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__6`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetResultsAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsy
```

and

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Test.ApplicationUserManager.GetLineMannagerByLogin(String login) in [...]
   at Test.Controllers.BaseController.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext authContext) in [...]
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
```

Comment: I wouldn't use OWIN as a container. This looks like an older .Net version that didn't come with an injector. You can use something like Ninject or Unity but that may be overkill. I would do the opposite of what you're doing (HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>()) and wrap a using statement around each instance.

Comment: @GHDevOps, I inherited the application, and I think I need to stick to it.

Comment: do you have a stacktrace of an error? one thing I can think of is that context is resolved using DI container (controller construction injection or GetOwinContext.Get) and then it is used inside asynchronous job (Task.Run) without awaiting. this way request will end, context will be disposed, but it will still be used inside asynchronous task, leading to error, which will not be caught anywhere globally

Comment: @YehorAndrosov post updated.

Comment: I am afraid it is too hard to understand the root of the issue without seeing and debugging the whole project. as i mentioned, the common issue to this is early completion of request. you need to confirm that you don't have any non-awaited background jobs, or manual writes to Response object etc. that might cause further code to operate on disposed object

Comment: Perhaps the problem is somewhere in this method Test.Controllers.BaseController.OnAuthorization

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the code for `Test.ApplicationUserManager.GetLineMannagerByLogin(String login)`

Answer (score 0):

> > I’m working on an ASP.NET MVC application that uses OWIN.

> > at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsy

> > The problem is that I get a random DbContext disposed (InvalidOperationException) issue when I run a query.

Sounds as if the query is for a related entity is Lazy loaded ie it wasn't loaded in the initial DB call, and then subsequently when you've tried to use the navigation property(related entity), the DbContext has been disposed. You've not supplied detalis on the function calls so not sure how your function call to the subsequent query is set up, but try and pass the DBContext from the original entity load. HTH.